# Propel ORM: Query searches for table name in starting character in uppercase

Tags: propel2

I am using Propel ORM

```
<table name="tawcompanyresearch" idMethod="native" phpName="Tawcompanyresearch">
<column name="TawCompanyResearchID" phpName="Tawcompanyresearchid" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
```

This is the generator in my schema.xml. When I make a query it returns as

> 42S02 - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'taw.Tawcompanyresearch' doesn't exist

Please note that the table name is in small letters but search result returns the first character of the table as capital.

Where can this value be changed? Please give me some insights of this error.
Thank You

Comment: What query did you try that led to this error?

Comment: This was an old question. I remember that I was running a select statement.